# How to predict on the Test data using random forest when "prediction" column is missing in the data set given?

Tags: r, random-forest

How to predict on the Test data using randomforest when "prediction" column (is_promoted) is ***missing in the TEST data set given?***

Here I have given two data sets: Train and Test, in Test data set I have to predict whether the employee will be promoted or not.

The Train data set **has the `is_promoted` column which has been used to build the model.** 
and I have used `Test$is_promoted=NA` to add the is_promoted column in my Test data set so that I **have equal dimensions during data preparation process.**

But when I am using Random forest to predict the final values it **shows those "NA" as missing value errors.**

```
set.seed(123)
rf_m3=randomForest(is_promoted~.,data = FinalTest,ntree=150, nodesize=50, mtry=5)
rf_test_pred=predict(rf_m3, FinalTest, type="class")
```

Error code:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(is_promoted = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  : 
  missing values in object
```

Now I can't remove "is_promoted" also as its my dependent variable.

So kindly suggest a way to handle this issue and the modification of the code required.

*PS: New learner. First time trying random forest, so if possible please explain as much as possible.*

Comment: Random forests is a _supervised_ machine learning method, which builds a model around a series of predictors and a _known_ response.  If you truly have no information on whether or not the subjects received a promotion, then you can't really use random forests.

Comment: The point of a test set is exactly that you don't have the variable you want to predict. So it's perfectly normal that `is_promoted` is missing. You shouldn't create such a column when using `predict`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your dependent variable contains NAs, that's why the error is coming. You can check it by `summary(FinalTest)`. If the is_promoted contains NA values (which I think is present) use

```
rf_m3 = randomForest(is_promoted~., data = FinalTest, ntree=150, nodesize=50, mtry=5, na.action=na.omit)
```